# How Can I Display Single Image From Array Of Images

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here My Codes That Fetch All Images

`@foreach (explode('|', $product->images) as $image) <img style="width:100%" src="/storage/image/{{$image}}"> @endforeach`

Only I want To Display the first image from this array How Can i Do That

Comment: Laravel has a [$loop](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable you could use

Comment: Explode the array and use array notation?

Comment: @Abrar if you satisfy with this my ans then mark as a right correct Ans, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So, just do it in the blade like this

```php
@if (!empty($product->images))
    @php
        $images = explode('|', $product->images);
    @endphp
    @if (count($images) > 0)
        <img style="width:100%" src="/storage/image/{{$images[0]}}">
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what the problem was, what you changed to make it work etc. instead of just dumping code so others can learn. Thanks

Comment: Okay will take care of it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

So, if you're passing the array from your controller to view/blade page then you should just do.

img src="/storage/image/{{$image[0]}}"

E.g $images = [
'image1.jpg',
'image2.jpg',
'image3.png',
'etc.jpg'
]

Then you pass $images

:Then call $images[1]